# Как получить координаты нажатия на системную клавиатуру iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Нужно получить координаты нажатия на системную клавиатуру, чтобы сделать тепловую карту. Подскажите как получить координаты или для системной клавиатуры это сделать нельзя.
Используя TapGestureRecognizer не пойму как добавить гестуру на клавиатуру, есть другие методы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для системной клавиатуры это сделать нельзя. Вы можете сделать свою клавиатуру, и сделать карту для неё.

Comment: а для кастамной клавиатуры какая реализация возможна?

Comment: Новые вопросы оформляйте как новые вопросы